# Button is not invoking button's css class but it is inheriting css class of parent div

Tags: html, css

Button is not invoking button's CSS class but it is inheriting CSS class of parent div
Can anyone help?

```css
.sq-ui-ban {
    background-color: #abacb1;
    color: black;
    width: 1000px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-style: normal;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    position: relative;
}

.moreBan {
    position: fixed;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: Calibri;
    background: #1c94c4;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border: none;
    font-size: large;
    padding: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sq-ui-ban">
<button class="moreBan"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down"></i><span class="moretext">More</span></button>
</div>
```

What is problem in this?

Comment: you DIV tag is not closed,

Comment: I closed it @AdnanAkram

Comment: Now it is showing nothing @AdnanAkram

Comment: need to remove position:absolute; from button or you can remove width from wrapper div ".sq-ui-ban"

Comment: May i know reason for why to remove position:absolute @AdnanAkram

Comment: Ok so a few things: .sq-ui-ban needs to have a set height, right now it's rendering as height:0px and so your .moreBan element which has an absolute position is basically drawing the button outside the view area.

Also you have 2 position properties in .moreBan

Comment: Yeah nice explanation Thank U @TingSun

Comment: Outer div ".sq-ui-ban "  have a width of 1000px  and inner button is position: absolute;  and you have used right so it hide on right side you can use left: 0; instead of right: 0; to see button, and also you have used overflow: hidden on .moreBan, it's better if you use height to on this DIV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `overflow:hidden` from `.sq-ui-ban` and give proper height, width, left and top(Or any position) value to button make your button visible.

Because button parent div height is auto and button is `position:absolute` so, parent div take no height and `overflow:hidden` will not allow button to display.

```css
.sq-ui-ban {
    background-color: #abacb1;
    color: black;
    width: 1000px;
    height: auto;
    font-style: normal;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    position: relative;
  
}

.moreBan {
    position: fixed;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: Calibri;
    background: #1c94c4;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border: none;
    font-size: large;
    padding: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="sq-ui-ban" id="banner">
<button class="moreBan"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down"></i><span class="moretext">More</span></button>
</div>
```